# Computing top n word pair co-occurrences from document term matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, gensim, text-analysis

I used gensim to create a bag of words model. Although it is much longer in reality, here is the format outputted when creating a bag of words document-term matrix on the tokenized texts using Gensim:

```
id2word = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

[[(0, 2),
  (1, 1),
  (2, 1),
  (3, 1),
  (4, 11),
  (385, 1),
  (386, 2),
  (387, 3),
  (388, 1),
  (389, 1),
  (390, 1)],
 [(4, 31),
  (8, 2),
  (13, 2),
  (16, 2),
  (17, 2),
  (26, 1),
  (28, 4),
  (29, 1),
  (30, 1)]]
```

This is a sparse matrix representation, and from what I understand other libraries represent the document-term matrix in a similar fashion as well. If the document-term matrix is non-sparse (meaning the zero entries are there as well), I know that I just have to (A.T*A), since A is of dimension (num. of documents by num. of terms), so multiplying the two will give the term co-occurrences. Ultimately, I want to get the top n co-occurrences (so get the top n term pairs that occur together in the same texts). How would I achieve this? I am not attached to Gensim for creating the BOW model. If another library like sklearn can do it more easily, I am very open. I would appreciate any advice/help/code with this problem -- thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Here is how you can achieve the matrix multiplication you asked about. Disclaimer: This might not be feasible for a very large corpus.

Sklearn:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

Doc1 = 'Wimbledon is one of the four Grand Slam tennis tournaments, the others being the Australian Open, the French Open and the US Open.'
Doc2 = 'Since the Australian Open shifted to hardcourt in 1988, Wimbledon is the only major still played on grass'
docs = [Doc1, Doc2]

# Instantiate CountVectorizer and apply it to docs
cv = CountVectorizer()
doc_cv = cv.fit_transform(docs)

# Display tokens
cv.get_feature_names()

# Display tokens (dict keys) and their numerical encoding (dict values)
cv.vocabulary_

# Matrix multiplication of the term matrix
token_mat = doc_cv.toarray().T @ doc_cv.toarray()
```

Gensim:

```
import gensim as gs
import numpy as np

cp = [[(0, 2),
  (1, 1),
  (2, 1),
  (3, 1),
  (4, 11),
  (7, 1),
  (11, 2),
  (13, 3),
  (22, 1),
  (26, 1),
  (30, 1)],
 [(4, 31),
  (8, 2),
  (13, 2),
  (16, 2),
  (17, 2),
  (26, 1),
  (28, 4),
  (29, 1),
  (30, 1)]]

# Convert to a dense matrix and perform the matrix multiplication
mat_1 = gs.matutils.sparse2full(cp[0], max(cp[0])[0]+1).reshape(1, -1)
mat_2 = gs.matutils.sparse2full(cp[1], max(cp[0])[0]+1).reshape(1, -1)
mat = np.append(mat_1, mat_2, axis=0)
mat_product = mat.T @ mat
```

For words that appear consecutively, you could prepare a list of bigrams for a set of documents and then use python's Counter to count the bigram occurrences. Here is an example using nltk.

```
import nltk
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from collections import Counter

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

# Get the tokens from the built-in collection of presidential inaugural speeches
tokens = nltk.corpus.inaugural.words()

# Futher text preprocessing
tokens = [t.lower() for t in tokens if t not in stop_words]
word_l = WordNetLemmatizer()
tokens = [word_l.lemmatize(t) for t in tokens if t.isalpha()]

# Create bigram list and count bigrams
bi_grams = list(ngrams(tokens, 2)) 
counter = Counter(bi_grams)

# Show the most common bigrams
counter.most_common(5)
Out[36]: 
[(('united', 'state'), 153),
 (('fellow', 'citizen'), 116),
 (('let', 'u'), 99),
 (('i', 'shall'), 96),
 (('american', 'people'), 40)]

# Query the occurrence of a specific bigram
counter[('great', 'people')]
Out[37]: 7
```

Comment: Thank for sharing! This only looks at words that occur consecutively, right? So if I understand correctly, it doesn't care whether words are mentioned frequently (but separated) in the same in the same document.

Comment: I didn't pick up on that originally! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have realised my original answer only applies to words that occur consecutively as you have suggested. Please see the updated answer for the matrix multiplication you have asked about. I am not sure this would work if you corpus has millions of words.